# How to get Database from azure with subscriptions disabled

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

I want to know about how to get Database from Microsoft azure with subscriptions disabled, my subscription **program benefit** was disabled after a year, now I have a new subscription **pay-as-you-go** but I can't move existing database from disabled account to my new account, or make a copy.

How can I do that?

Comment: How do you get data from a service you are no longer subscribed to? Re-subscribe I think would be the answer...

Comment: You need to contact support

Comment: I can't Re-subscribe, it's a Developer Program Benefit for one year only and no more, I just want pass dato to my other subscriptions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a customer support issue. Nothing can really be done here.